# -bash: apt-get: command not found

Tags: mac-osx, unix, bash, apt, terminal

Over the course of uninstalling the HP/palm enyo SDK and installing node JS I somehow goofed up something (I think my path).

Now when I try use apt-get I get the following:

```
-bash: apt-get: command not found
```

I'm not really sure how to fix this. Here is my $PATH

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/wesbos/local/node/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/PalmSDK/0.1/bin/
```

Using OSX Lion but problem was persistent with Snow Leopard

Comment: Did you use MacPorts or Fink to get apt-get on your Lion box? Fink doesn't support Lion yet.

Comment: I didnt use either. I installed macports to try and fix the issue but to no avail.

Comment: Perhaps we should back up a bit. How did you get apt on your Mac in the first place since it's not shipped with OS X?

Comment: :| I'm not sure. Does it come with xcode? I've always just had it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool `apt-get` is not a part of the Apple OSX family of products, and as such should not be expected to be found on a typical installation. One can, however, install apt, as a front-end for dpkg, using MacPorts. How useful, or advisable this would actually be is left as an exercise to the reader. To install said packages, one should perform the following command sequence.

```
/opt/local/bin/port selfupdate
/opt/local/bin/port install dpkg
/opt/local/bin/port install apt
```

After this, you're on your own....

Answer (score 2):

I don't like macports.. I prefer homebrew

[Link](https://brew.sh/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the executable. The symlink may have been lost

```
    locate apt-get
```

or

```
    find / -name apt-get
```

You can then restore the symlink if it's found with

```
    ln -s /path/to/apt-get /usr/bin/apt-get
```